# Reading vector-dataset with rgrass7

Tags: r, grass-gis, vector, rgrass7

I have read in some vector data with rgrass7 and produced some output Layers using Grass in R. Now I wanted to import one of the created layers back into R and convert it into an `sf`- object. When I try to run the follwing code I get the message that I need to provide either `sf` or `sp`. But I don' really know where I could do this in the `readVECT`-function(). Any hint would be super helpful.

```
Error in readVECT("streets") : 
  either sp or sf must be chosen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `plugin` argument or `set.pluginOption` function(s) are all about. If you read the help for `readVECT` you will see under the plugin argument:

> default NULL if which case it will be set to the value set by
>   set.pluginOption; NULL for auto-detection, may be set to FALSE to
>   avoid or TRUE if the plugin is known to be available; if the plugin is
>   used, no further arguments other than mapset are respected

Then, if you take a look at the help for `set.pluginOption` you will see the options that are causing this error. Rather than passing these to the plugin argument you should just be able to issue `use_sp()` or `use_sf()` at some point before calling `readVECT` and it will set the global preference for the R session. These are new options so, previous code would have worked without specifying either of these functions or the plugin argument.

Comment: tank you very very much!!